# Should I use a CSS grid system for this template?

Tags: html, css

This might be the wrong place to ask but...

I want to convert the following template to HTML and CSS. Should I use a grid system such as bootstrap or skeleton? 
Seeing as it's already a grid it seems to make sense.

I get the feeling that bootstrap would be overkill if I'm only using the grid system.
I would like it to be responsive but also work across a good range of browsers.

[image: template]

Comment: This question looks like a candidate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Personally, I would use Bootstrap JS. I actually paid for a framework  https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S  Since buying it, I have seen ***extremely*** similar versions for free, so probably the one I bought was based on a  free one. Google around for one (or pay $18). It supports the Bootstrap grid system

Answer (score 1):

Using a grid system will be very helpful for such a template and will allow you to go faster for implementing the responsiveness. There is no need for reinventing the wheel.

You could use alternative CSS frameworks like [Pure.css](http://purecss.io) which is pretty light and well designed. There is also a possibility to use only the grid (under the customize tab).

Otherwise there is a [list of CSS framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_frameworks#List_of_CSS_frameworks) on Wikipedia where you will surely find one that fits your expectations.